# Add divs with text in container from bottom to top

Tags: html, position

Is it possible adding div with text message in big div container from bottom to top? I want start listing my chat messages from bottom. Any new div with message I need add below existing div with old message (at the bottom hole container).

Thanks.

```
  <div id="public_message_container" style="overflow:auto;width:500px;height:300px;">
    <div class='public_message'><b>Nick1:</b> Message1</div>
    <div class='public_message'><b>Nick2:</b> Message2</div>
    <div class='public_message'><b>Nick3:</b> Message3</div>
    <div class='public_message'><b>Nick4:</b> Message4</div>
</div>
```

When I add dynamicly messages1-4 I want it show from bottom to top, as they come.

Comment: It is of course possible - but that depends on your CSS + HTML. There are many solutions. Please edit your question to be more specific (show some work).

Comment: Javascript can do this. Use Ajax to update the page. These links can help you learn how to add new elements dynamically to the page: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_document_createelement.asp http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_appendchild.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the last child of the container, then insert using `.after()`

```
$("#public_message_container div").last().after("<div class='public_message'><b>Nick5:</b> Message5</div>")
```